# SCIM endpoint. Error when testing from Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, scim

Getting below error while integrating the SCIM endpoint with Azure AD. Any idea whats wrong?

You appear to have entered invalid credentials. Please confirm you are using the correct information for an administrative account.

Error code: SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementCredentialValidationUnavailable
Details: We received this unexpected response from your application:

We are not able to deserilize the resouce received from your SCIM endpoint because your SCIM endpoint is not fully compatible with the Azure Active Directory SCIM client. Here is the resouce we received from your SCIM endpoint:

```
 [{"enterpriseExtension":{"manager":null,"costCenter":null,"department":null,"division":null,"employeeNumber":null,"organization":null},"active":true,"addresses":null,"customExtension":{},"displayName":null,"electronicMailAddresses":null,"instantMessagings":null,"locale":null,"metadata":{"resourceType":"User"},"name":{"formatted":null,"familyName":"Badipetle","givenName":"Ravi","honorificPrefix":null,"honorificSuffix":null},"nickname":null,"phoneNumbers":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"roles":null,"timeZone":null,"title":null,"userType":null,"userName":"Ravi","externalIdentifier":"4598ec28-2b7e-4605-88ec-9c1758327ec2","identifier":"1fdffc66-2190-4327-bafb-ef726223cffd","schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User","urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"]}]
```

Please refer to the Azure Active Directory SCIM provisioning documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups) and adapt the SCIM endpoint to be able to process provisioning requests from Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Do you have users with multi-valued attributes?

Comment: The user details seen above above is created in memory in the GET call

Answer (score 2):

Azure validation stage is calling /User?filter=id eq 8khsf73-23kh7-234lj
the expected result of "filter" is NOT array.
it is ListResponse

```
{
  "resources": [],
  "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"],
  "totalResults": 0
}
```

and note that on validation stage, Azure is expecting 0 results.